# Cómo hacer iloc en Pandas por id de producto

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Quiero seleccionar los siguientes elementos [86833, 1023897, 130365, 76863], que son las ids de mis productos, en este DataFrame:

```
index    type   username  product  count
    0  access  45michael    63767      0
    1  access     7762hc    84325      0
    2  access   adrian12   997165      0
    3  access   kerrigan   130365      0
    4  access      yvera    76863      0
    5   order  45michael    76863      1
    6   order  45michael    86833      1
```

Pero cuando intento ejecutar `order_df.iloc[products]`, donde products es el array de ids que quiero seleccionar, me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

Cómo puedo hacer un mapping del index con las ids de productos para poder seleccionar en el DataFrame por id de producto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No lo puedo comprobar ahora pero me parece que la opción sería emplear `isin()`

```
valores= [86833, 1023897, 130365, 76863]
df = df[df['product'].isin(valores)]
```

Con esto lo que podrás es obtener aquellas filas que contienen los valores definidos en la columna `product`.

Si esto no te funciona, lo miramos más a fondo!!

Comment: Funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias!